# Lateinit variable is not initialized in TestNG's @BeforeSuite

Tags: java, kotlin, testng, appium

I am trying to lateinit variable (`AppiumDriver` service) for my testNG tests in `@BeforeSuite` method like this:

```kotlin
abstract class BaseTest {

    lateinit var driver: AppiumDriver<MobileElement>

    @Parameters("platform")
    @BeforeSuite(alwaysRun = true)
    fun init(platform: String) {
        Configuration.isIOS = platform.lowercase() == "ios"
        driver = <driver initialization>
        println(driver)
    }
}
```

My tests then look like this:

```kotlin
class MedicationsTests : BaseTest() {
    fun test_01() {
        // Test using `driver` variable
    }
}
```

`@BeforeSuite` method `init(String)` is running before tests start (I see output of print), but then I am getting errror, when method `test_01()` is trying to use `driver` variable:

```kotlin
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property driver has not been initialized
```

It is working perfectly fine in `@BeforeClass`, but I want to run this initialization only once per whole suite, not once per class...

Any ideas how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestNG will create a new instance of BaseTest class for you per each test.
If you want to share your driver - make it static. Example:

```
abstract class BaseTest {
    companion object {
        lateinit var driver: AppiumDriver<MobileElement>
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixed my issue thank you so much